# What is the best approach to make image cropping control like in 'CamScanner' App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I intend to make a image cropping control like the one given in the below picture. Please tell me the best controls and native objects to use for drawing these circles and lines and for manipulation and changes calculations on touch events.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily make it by customizing [JBCroppableView](https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView).

Comment: Thanks, man. I was sure for such a demo but couldn't find one before!